# Understanding spring and annotations, what do I have to wireup in my xml config files

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm a little confused, in my servlet-context.xml I have:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />
```

and

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

So the above seem to automatically wireup my controllers, service classes etc.

I'm using hibernate, I still have to write a new xml entry for every Entity I have, is this correct?

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <mapping package="com.myapp.core.model"/>

        <mapping class="com.myapp.core.model.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.myapp.core.model.Product"/>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

And also for every EntityDao class like UserDao I need to add:

```
<bean id="userDao" class="com.myapp.core.doa.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Can't the above 2 (entity and entityDao) be autowired so I don't have to touch the xml files ?

Also, I was following an example of a maven/pom project and I have this in my pom.xml, does this mean spring will use javax.inject as its dependancy injector engine?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Update**

My UserDaoImpl looks like:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User, Integer> implements UserDao {

    @Resource
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

I tried this also and got the same results:

```
@Resource
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Spring

Spring as well can be instructed to use annotations. And again you can use native annotations like `@Autowired` or standard ones like `@Resource` and `@Inject`. Here is a taste of what you can do:

```
@Repository
class UserDaoImpl {

    @Resource
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //...

}
```

In fact with not yet release Spring 3.1 you can write the whole Spring/MVC/Hibernate application without even a single line of XML. See my small [showcase](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/spring-pitfalls) here.

#### Hibernate

You can use [annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html) and instruct Spring/Hibernate to pick them up. Hibernate has native annotations but try to use the standard JPA first.

Again a simple example:

```
@Entity
class User {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Product> products;

}
```

Comment: I do that @Entity on my entities already, not sure why it didn't pick it up?  I'll try the others and report back thanks.

Comment: btw, my UserDaoImpl is extending GenericDaoImpl, could I just wire up SessionFactory there so I dont' have to do it in each DaoImpl class? Or does it have to be private?

Comment: @Blankman: yes you can, just make it `protected`. Don't know why the Hibernate annotations aren't picked up, can you provide more details?

Comment: error: core/doa/UserDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required

Comment: @Blankman - You can find a [tutorial](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html) to configure Spring with hibernate. Its not necessary to create separate hibernate configuration xml. Instead of specifying explicit list of entity classes you can also specify the 'packagesToScan' property.